# PyMongo: filter collection by date and group by a particular field

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

im new using python and pymongo and im trying to build a query to get all the tasks and the resultCount for each one of the tasks that were executed one specific date.

One task can be executed more than once so, i need to get the last executed one.

right now i accomplished to bring all the tasks executed in the current day, but couldn't filter them by last one executed when the task has the same name.

Could you help me please?

My mongoDB contains the following data:

```
[{"_id":1, "executionDate":"2021-04-20T10:11:37-03:00", "taskName":"fix1", "error":true, "resultCount":25},
{"_id":2, "executionDate":"2021-04-20T11:11:37-03:00",  "taskName":"fix2", "error":false, "resultCuont":25},
{"_id":3, "executionDate":"2021-04-20T12:11:37-03:00",  "taskName":"fix1", "error":true, "resultCount":3},
{"_id":4, "executionDate":"2021-04-20T13:11:37-03:00",  "taskName":"fix3", "error":false, "resultCunt":78},
{"_id":5, "executionDate":"2021-04-20T14:11:37-03:00",  "taskName":"fix3", "error":false, "resultCount":85}]
```

my query looks something like this:

```
docs = db.aggregate([{"$match": {"executionDate": {"$gt": todays_date}, "error": False}}, {"$group": {"_id": "$taskName"}}])
```

Comment: You can group  by task and find the maximum ( use the [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) aggregation operator) of the executed date. Also, see [Group Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#calculate-count--sum--and-average).

Comment: Many thanks @prasad_ i had to add some few things but worked like a charm. Best regards!